# How to update/refresh a destination using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation

It's simple yet I cannot find an answer. Say I have this destination and I desire to refresh it upon the click of a button or whatsoever, how would we do it? I assume we need to destroy and recreate it right after? Or is there a simpler way? I was looking for something similar to `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: What do you mean refresh it? There's no concept of refreshing in fragments, other than the one you implement by yourself. If what you want is to update the theme or something like that, it's usually done with configuration changes and handled by the system, which recreates the activity and the fragments.

Comment: Your data source should already be giving you a callback when your data changes. You haven't provided any details on how exactly you load your data, what your Fragment does, or any other details.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I see what you guys mean. I have this ViewModel holding the data of a single object in that destination I am trying to "refresh". On a press of a button, some of that data needs to change and it doesnt seem to do it. So I though re creating my fragment was my only option.